# Find field type in mongodb using query

Tags: mongodb

I have collection containing some fields.

Document structure is here:

```
    {
      date: ISODate("2014-03-19T23:00:00Z"),
      value: 25.8,
      name:"MyName"
    }
```

is there is way to find out data type of field?
how I can identify key `value` data type? either it is `double` or `float`

Comment: Fields don't have types. The same field in different documents (or, say, the same field in different array elements in one document) could be any of the supported BSON types. You can search for documents where the value of a specific field is of a specific type using `$type` as detailed below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB stores data in bson format. And if you have a look at this link : [Bson data types spec](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/)

You will see that bson does not have a datatype called 'float' , it only has 'double' . Hence you cannot differentiate between 'float' and 'double'. But you can determine the data type of other fields like 'Date'.

Comment: But how can I determine data type using query?

Comment: Syntax: { field: { $type: <BSON type> } }

$type selects the documents where the type of the field is the specified BSON type.

Consider the following example:

db.collection.find( { name: { $type : 2 } } )

Since type '2' refers to String, this selects the documents where the value of the field 'name' is "String" type.